# How to change the state hook with nested objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update my state, i have the following one:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
   exampleValue: 280.0
 });
```

And here is the function where i try to update it

```
function handleValuesChanged(field, value) {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      field: value,
    });
  }
```

Here's the input

```
<Input
   {...field}
   classes={{
     root: styles.root,
     input: styles.input,
   }}
   inputProps={{ type: 'number', min: 0 }}
   id={field.name}
   onChange={e => props.handleValues(field.name, e.target.value)}
/>
```

Instead of change the `exampleValue` state value (That name is sent in the `field` parameter, and the new value comes in the `value` parameter), it creates a new field called `field` with the new value.

If i put `exampleValue` in hard code in the `setValues` function, it does what i want, but when i try to use the `field` parameter, it creates a new state field.

Writing a value of 500, i expect the state changes to:

```
exampleValue: 500
```

Instead of that, i get

```
exampleValue: 280.0
field: 500
```

Does anybody knows how to can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the value of variable `field` as the key, not the string `"field"` =>

```
setValues({
  ...values,
  [field]: value,
})
```

*Note*: `{field: 1}` is a shorthand for `{"field": 1}`,  `{field}` is a shorthand for `{"field": field}`. See [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for more details.